# Computing c-index for an external validation of a Cox PH model with R

Tags: r, regression, cox-model, validation, rms

First off, I'll state that I'm aware many questions get asked about the c-index.  I've searched this site and others, and I haven't found an answer for my situation.  I can successfully use `validate()` in the `rms` package to calculate the Dxy and c-index for my boot-strapped internal validation.  Now I need a c-index for my external validation.

I just externally validated my model with an independent data set, and produced the desired plot of actual vs. predicted probabilities using `val.surv()`.  Unfortunately the abstract I'm submitting cannot have figures, so I feel compelled to report a c-index for the external validation.  I have searched this site and the R help archive and haven't found a conclusive answer for how to calculate the c-index on external validation.

I've seen mentions of using `rcorr.cens()` in the `Hmisc` package, but it seems to me that you can only use it for a single variable's concordance, not an entire model.  As of yet I can't find a way to use `val.surv()` for calculating a c-index as well.  I posted some sample code below, including a test data set to act like an external validation set.

I really appreciate your help in calculating a c-index from an external validation with an independent data set.

```
library(rms)
library(Hmisc)
data(veteran)

##Create a Cox PH model for the training data.
survmod=with(veteran,Surv(time,status))
cox.mod=cph(survmod~celltype+karno,data=veteran,x=T,y=T,surv=TRUE,time.inc=5*365)

##Here is the test data set that is the external "independent" data.
test_dat=data.frame(trt=replicate(500,NA), celltype=replicate(500,NA), time=replicate(500,NA), status=replicate(500,NA), karno=replicate(500,NA), diagtime=replicate(500,NA), age=replicate(500,NA), prior=replicate(500,NA))
for(i in seq(8)){
test_dat[,i]=sample(veteran[,i],500,replace=T)
}

##Validate the model with the test data
test_surv=with(test_dat,Surv(time,status))
validated=val.surv(cox.mod,newdata=test_dat,S=test_surv)

##Now what I need is to take the external validation and compute the 
#c-index.  This is where I'm stuck.  
#I've seen people mention `rcorr.cens()`, but I can't figure out a way to use 
#`rcorr.cens()` with a Cox model of several variables.  I appreciate your help!
```

Answer (score 10):

I just got an explanation from a colleague about how to use this feature.  In the help page for `rcorr.cens()`, it states that `x` is a "numeric predictor variable".  I thought that this meant it had to be a model variable like Age, Stage, Metastasis, etc.  What I found out is that `x` can just be a vector of your model's survival estimates for an external data set.  Therefore the only two things `rcorr.cens()` needs is that vector of survival estimates and a `Surv()` object.  Using my code from above, this is how you use it:

```
library(rms)
surv.obj=with(veteran,Surv(time,status))   ####This will be used for rcorr.cens
cox.mod=cph(surv.obj~celltype+karno,data=veteran,x=T,y=T,surv=TRUE,time.inc=5*365)

##Here is the test data set that is the external "independent" data.
test_dat=data.frame(trt=replicate(500,NA), celltype=replicate(500,NA), time=replicate(500,NA), status=replicate(500,NA), karno=replicate(500,NA), diagtime=replicate(500,NA), age=replicate(500,NA), prior=replicate(500,NA))
for(i in seq(8)){
test_dat[,i]=sample(veteran[,i],500,replace=T)
}

###Create your survival estimates
estimates=survest(cox.mod,newdata=test_dat,times=5*365)$surv


###Determine concordance
rcorr.cens(x=estimates,S=surv.obj)
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future who has the same question!

Comment: This is correct.  Or just use the linear predictor in the call to `rcorr.cens` if you do not have any strata.  Take $D_{xy}$ from the output in that case, negate it, and use the relationship $D_{xy} = 2\times (C - \frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: The final line of code doesn't work. I think you need to use 137 instead of 500 so as to match initial n in veteran data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package, which is a component of bioconductor that can help you calculate the c-index : [survcomp](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/survcomp.html)

If you don't include survival data, than cindex in survcomp is basically the same as the AUC you get from the ROC curve.

Answer (score 1):

I think code provided by @JJM could work with some changes.
The point raised by  @Seanosapien could be addressed by following edited code.

```
library(rms)
surv.obj=with(veteran,Surv(time,status))   ####This will NOT be used for rcorr.cens
cox.mod=cph(surv.obj~celltype+karno,data=veteran,x=T,y=T,surv=TRUE,time.inc=5*365)

##Here is the test data set that is the external "independent" data.
test_dat=data.frame(trt=replicate(500,NA), celltype=replicate(500,NA), 
time=replicate(500,NA), status=replicate(500,NA), karno=replicate(500,NA), 
diagtime=replicate(500,NA), age=replicate(500,NA), prior=replicate(500,NA))
for(i in seq(8)){
   test_dat[,i]=sample(veteran[,i],500,replace=T)
   }

Surv.obj_test=with(test_dat,Surv(time,status)) #This will be used for rcorr.cens

###Create your survival estimates
estimates=survest(cox.mod,newdata=test_dat,times=5*365)$surv


###Determine concordance
rcorr.cens(x=estimates,S=Surv.obj_test)
```

The change I have made is that `Surv()` object is created for the test data `Surv.obj_test`. This will allow `rcorr.cens` to compare the `estimates` with the test data `test_dat`.

The `estimates` enable in getting survival estimates using the model `cox_mod`. These estimates are compared with the `test_dat` "time" and "status" variable using the `rcorr.cens`.