# Cross validation and computing c index

Tags: r, cross-validation, cox-model

I have seen the discussion in the page [Computing c-index for an external validation of a Cox PH model with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/computing-c-index-for-an-external-validation-of-a-cox-ph-model-with-r). I am doing almost the same thing, using 3-fold sampling (with two thirds in the training set and one third in the test set) to do cross validation of cox regression model. When I was trying do `rcorr.cen`, it gave me the error message `Error in rcorr.cens(x = estimates, S = survmod) : y must have same length as x`. That is, I need to have same size for `x` and `s`. But `survmod` had been done on the training set and `x=estimates` on the test set. Do I need to use the same size for test and training to do that? Or can I continue with this set to calculate the c-index to communicate training and test data set?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user28298. It is not clear to me whether you are looking for help understanding the statistical ideas here, or w/ the R codes. If it's the latter, this Q would be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)), but on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a substantive statistical question, please edit to clarify; if not, flag your Q & we'll migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).