# Concordance index in survival and rms packages

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, concordance

I would like to compute concordance index to validate Cox model. From the following post [concordance rms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/computing-c-index-for-an-external-validation-of-a-cox-ph-model-with-r) I know that I can use `rms` package and `rcorr.cens` function. My concern is that Concordance index reported by `rms` is different from the one reported by the summary of `coxph` model from `survival` package. Here is my example:

```
library('survival')
library('rms')
data('vetera')
validation_obj <- Surv(time = veteran$time, event = veteran$status)
m.coxph <-coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ celltype+prior, data =veteran)
summary(m.coxph)$concordance
forecast <- predict(m.coxph,veteran[,c('celltype', 'prior')] )
rcorr.cens(x=forecast, S=validation_obj)
```

So `summary(m.coxph)$concordance` returns 0.61330077
while `rcorr.cens(x=forecast, S=validation_obj)` returns 3.866992e-01

Does anybody know reason for discrepancy?

**Update**

I just noticed that two concordance indices add up to 1, and it does not look like coincidence.

**Another Update**
So it looks like the above computations are somewhat meaningless: `forecast <- predict(m.coxph,veteran[,c('celltype', 'prior')] )` returns linear combination of coefficients and independent variables. So prediction is a part of hazard function, while `S=validation_obj` is survival object. Survival and hazard have opposite directions, so in order for code to work one needs to multiply hazard by `-1`. Here is corrected line: `rcorr.cens(x=forecast*(-1), S=validation_obj)`