# Cox PH - R 'rms' package - Concordance (Train, CV & Test)

Tags: r, regression, cox-model, proportional-hazards

Please could someone verify if my methodology for calculating these three versions of concordance are correct when using the `rms` package? I have really struggled to find many examples for performing cross-validation & test concordance, in particular.

I am working on a dataset of ~550k rows at work, but please see the reproducible example below:

```
library(rms)
library(caret)

set.seed(1)

index <- createDataPartition(veteran$status, p = 0.6, list = F)
veteran_train <- veteran[index, ] # 60%
veteran_test <- veteran[-index, ] # 40%

cox <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ karno + celltype, 
           data = veteran_train, 
           x = T, 
           y = T)
```

Using the relationship: $C = \frac{D_{xy} + 1}{2}$

**'Train' Concordance:**

```
train_C <- as.numeric((cox$stats[9] + 1)/2)
round(train_C, 4) # 0.7236
```

**'Train' (10-fold CV) Concordance:**

```
cv_version <- validate(cox, method = "crossvalidation", B = 10)
train_CV_C <- (cv_version[1, 3] + 1)/2
round(train_CV_C, 4) # 0.7167
```

**'Test' Concordance:**

```
actuals <- Surv(veteran_test$time, veteran_test$status)
estimates <- survest(cox, newdata = veteran_test, times = 1337)$surv # can pick an arbitrary time here, same results
test_C <- as.numeric(rcorr.cens(x = estimates, S = actuals)[1])
round(test_C, 4) # 0.6977
```

I investigated the `rms` package after attempting to find the test concordance through the `survival` package.

However I think (please confirm) `survival::concordance()` is bugged when specifying the `newdata` argument, only running if `veteran_test` has the exact same number of rows as `veteran_train`:

```
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ karno + celltype, data = veteran_train)
# test_C_v2 <- survival::concordance(cox, newdata = veteran_test)$concordance
```

This returns: `Error... x and y are not the same length`.

If I then create a situation where `veteran_train` & `veteran_test` *do* have the same number of rows, I get different test concordance results to the `rms` package!:

```
veteran_train <- veteran_train[1:nrow(veteran_test), ]
nrow(veteran_train) == nrow(veteran_test) # 41


# 'rms' method:
cox_rms <- rms::cph(Surv(time, status) ~ karno + celltype, 
           data = veteran_train, 
           x = T, 
           y = T)

actuals <- Surv(veteran_test$time, veteran_test$status)
estimates <- survest(cox_rms, newdata = veteran_test, times = 1337)$surv
test_C_v1 <- as.numeric(rcorr.cens(x = estimates, S = actuals)[1])
round(test_C_v1, 4) # 0.6977


# 'survival' method
cox_survival <- survival::coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ karno + celltype, data = veteran_train)

test_C_v2 <- survival::concordance(cox_survival, newdata = veteran_test)$concordance
round(test_C_v2, 4) # 0.4333
```

Is one of these approaches correct? When applying this methodology to my data, there was a common theme that the train/CV/test Concordance were all very close when using the `rms` package.

However, when using the `survival` package, the test concordance would see a significant drop (e.g. 0.7 train -> 0.55 test), which doesn't seem believable for a model with just one predictor and a large volume of data.

Comment: As an aside, split-sample validation is not reliable unless N > 20,000.  It's too dependent on the luck of the split, so is volatile.

Comment: I have not had experience with `survival::concordance` with `newdata`.  I hope to look at that soon.  Your usage of `rms` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your RMS method solution agrees with the solution that Frank Harrell approved in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/computing-c-index-for-an-external-validation-of-a-cox-ph-model-with-r) answer. I've found survest to be extremely slow, particularly when running predictions for >10 bootstrap re-samples of test folds. But aside from code performance, the accuracy of the calculations should be more robust. HTH.